# Unarchive Array with NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedunarchiver, ios12

Since upgrading to Swift 4.2 I've found that many of the NSKeyedUnarchiver and NSKeyedArchiver methods have been deprecated and we must now use the type method `static func unarchivedObject<DecodedObjectType>(ofClass: DecodedObjectType.Type, from: Data) -> DecodedObjectType?` to unarchive data.

I have managed to successfully archive an Array of my bespoke class WidgetData, which is an NSObject subclass:

```
private static func archiveWidgetDataArray(widgetDataArray : [WidgetData]) -> NSData {

    guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: widgetDataArray as Array, requiringSecureCoding: false) as NSData
        else { fatalError("Can't encode data") }

    return data

}
```

The problem comes when I try to unarchive this data:

```
static func loadWidgetDataArray() -> [WidgetData]? {

    if isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: USER_DEFAULTS_KEY_WIDGET_DATA) {

        if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_KEY_WIDGET_DATA) as? Data {

            //THIS FUNCTION HAS NOW BEEN DEPRECATED:
            //return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? [WidgetData]

            guard let nsArray = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: unarchivedObject as Data) else {
                fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data")
            }

            guard let array = nsArray as? Array<WidgetData> else {
                fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't get Array")
            }

            return array

        }

    }

    return nil

}
```

But this fails, as using `Array.self` instead of `NSArray.self` is disallowed. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this to unarchive my Array?

Comment: Check this for a more swifty solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460950/5820010

Comment: What "fails"?  What output do you get?  You aren't using `Array.self` anywhere.

Comment: When changed to Array.self instead of NSArray.self, the pre-compiler complains: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'ofClass:from:', expected 'ofClasses:from:') Replace 'ofClass' with 'ofClasses'. Which implies Array.self can't be used. When I use NSArray.self it compiles without issue & runs. But gets caught by the fatal error as the resulting 'nsArray' is nil.

Comment: So, what happens when you use `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [Array<WidgetData>.self], from: unarchivedObject as Data)`? Also, instead of using `try?` use `do/try/catch` so that you can print the actual error that occurred.

Comment: It results in the following complaint:
Cannot convert value of type 'Array<WidgetData>.Type' to expected element type 'AnyObject.Type' Insert ' as! AnyObject.Type'

Comment: guard let unarchivedFavorites = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(favoritesData!)
                else {
                    return
            }
            self.channelFavorites = unarchivedFavorites as! [ChannelFavorite]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:)` to unarchive the data archived by `archivedData(withRootObject:requiringSecureCoding:)`. (I believe this is not deprecated yet.)

But before showing some code, you should better:

- Avoid using `NSData`, use `Data` instead
- Avoid using `try?` which disposes error info useful for debugging
- Remove all unneeded casts

---

Try this:

```
private static func archiveWidgetDataArray(widgetDataArray : [WidgetData]) -> Data {
    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: widgetDataArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)

        return data
    } catch {
        fatalError("Can't encode data: \(error)")
    }

}

static func loadWidgetDataArray() -> [WidgetData]? {
    guard
        isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: USER_DEFAULTS_KEY_WIDGET_DATA), //<- Do you really need this line?
        let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_KEY_WIDGET_DATA)
    else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        guard let array = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as? [WidgetData] else {
            fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't get Array")
        }
        return array
    } catch {
        fatalError("loadWidgetDataArray - Can't encode data: \(error)")
    }
}
```

---

But if you are making a new app, you should better consider using `Codable`.

Comment: That hit the nail on the head. Thank you so much. Yes, I'm making a new app. If you could shed a little light on Codable.. You got my attention. Where should I start with it & why is it important.

Comment: @GeoffH, it's native Swift way of serializing (archiving). (For example, it works with `[WidgetData].self`, you have no need to care about `NSArray` or some other `NS`-things.) Better start with searching "swift codable" and you can find many good articles.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you so much.

Comment: how we can do for let dictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [String: Element]? its deprecated now and     typealias Element = [String: Any]

Answer (score 26):

```
unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:)
```

is deprecated as well. So to unarchive data without secure coding you need to:

1. Create `NSKeyedUnarchiver` with `init(forReadingFrom: Data)`
2. Set `requiresSecureCoding` of created unarchiver to false.
3. Call `decodeObject(of: [AnyClass]?, forKey: String) -> Any?` to get your object, just use proper class and `NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey`as key.

Comment: For anyone archiving data using NSKeyedArchiver (with or without requiringSecureCoding), this is the answer.  Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

As **unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData** is also deprecated after iOS 14.3 only the [Hopreeeenjust's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52758898/286361) is correct now.

But if you don't need NSSecureCoding you also can use [answer of Maciej S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52434245/286361)

It is very easy to use it, by adding extension to NSCoding protocol:

```
extension NSCoding where Self: NSObject {
    static func unsecureUnarchived(from data: Data) -> Self? {
        do {
            let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
            unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = false
            let obj = unarchiver.decodeObject(of: self, forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey)
            if let error = unarchiver.error {
                print("Error:\(error)")
            }
            return obj
        } catch {
            print("Error:\(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

With this extension to unarchive e.g. NSArray you only need:

```
let myArray = NSArray.unsecureUnarchived(from: data)
```

For Objective C use NSObject category:

```
+ (instancetype)unsecureUnarchivedFromData:(NSData *)data {
NSError * err = nil;
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData: data error: &err];
unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = NO;
id res = [unarchiver decodeObjectOfClass:self forKey:NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey];
err = err ?: unarchiver.error;
if (err != nil) {
    NSLog(@"NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObject error: %@", err);
}
return  res;
```

}

Note that if the requiresSecureCoding is false, class of unarchived object is not actually checked and objective c code returns valid result even if it is called from wrong class.
And swift code when called from wrong class returns nil (because of optional casting), but without error.

Comment: I cannot stress how much I am gratified that this answer exists. Given that the accepted answer suggests something that is also going to be deprecated, having an answer that will hopefully work indefinitely is extremely useful.

Comment: This is the best

Answer (score 6):

You are likely looking for this:

```
if let widgetsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: USER_DEFAULTS_KEY_WIDGET_DATA) {
        if let widgets = (try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, WidgetData.self], from: widgetsData)) as? [WidgetData] {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: I could resolve a same problem with your approach using ‘[NSArray.self, WidgetData.self]’. However I cound not find a public document about your approach. Do you know document url?

Answer (score 5):

***Swift 5- IOS 13***

```
guard let mainData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "eventDetail") as? NSData
else {
    print(" data not found in UserDefaults")
    return
}
do {
    guard let finalArray =
    try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(mainData as Data) as? [EventDetail]
    else {
        return
    }
    self.eventDetail = finalArray
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        guard let unarchivedFavorites = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(favoritesData!)
            else {
                return
        }
        self.channelFavorites = unarchivedFavorites as! [ChannelFavorite]
    } else {
        if let unarchivedFavorites = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: favoritesData!) as? [ChannelFavorite] {
            self.channelFavorites = unarchivedFavorites
        }
```

// Achieving data

```
 if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
            // use iOS 12-only feature
            do {
                let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: channelFavorites, requiringSecureCoding: false)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "channelFavorites")
            } catch {
                return
            }
        } else {
            // handle older versions
            let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: channelFavorites)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "channelFavorites")
        }
```

This is the way I have updated my code and its working for me

Comment: Your availability macros don't make sense. In the first code block, why is it there? `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData()` was introduced in iOS 9, and deprecated in iOS 12.

Answer (score -1):

This is just slightly different from Hopreeeenjust answer above. Anyway, I like his answer as it's simple and uses the syntax that Apple recommends.

```
    if let archivedData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "myKey") as? Data {
        do {
            if let myArray = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSString.self], from: archivedData) as? [String] {
             myPreviouslyDefinedArray = myArray
            }
        } catch {
             print("read error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```