# Archive and Unarchive an array of UIColours to NSUserDefaults in iOS 12?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, uicolor, nskeyedarchiver

I'm still new to Swift and i'm trying archive and unarchive an array of UIColours to NSUserDefaults. I'm aware that in ios 12 i need to use `unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)` - but i'm not sure how to use that. 

I've tried to follow this question: [Unarchive Array with NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487622/unarchive-array-with-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchivedobjectofclassfrom?rq=1)
but i think i'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code i am trying:

```
let faveColoursArray = [colour1, colour2]

private func archiveColours() -> Data {

    do {
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: faveColoursArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)

        return data
    } catch {
        fatalError("can't encode data.")
    }


}


   func loadColours() -> [UIColor]? {

      guard let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "faveColours") else {
          return nil
      }

      do {
          guard let array = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: UIColor.self, from: unarchivedObject) else {
            fatalError("Can't load colours.")
        }
        return array
      } catch {
          fatalError("Can't load colours.")
      }

  }
```

Thankyou

Comment: Does this work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30576832/5078779

Comment: That's a good idea, i will give it a shot, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(_:)`:

```
func loadColours() -> [UIColor]? {
    guard let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "faveColours") else {
      return nil
    }

    do {
      guard let array = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as? [UIColor] else {
        fatalError("Can't load colours.")
      }
      return array
    } catch {
      fatalError("Can't load colours.")
    }

}
```