# How to NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject

Tags: swift, ios12, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a working code that works but deprecated:

This part is fine:

```
 let archived = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [defaultRecord] as NSArray, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

This is Deprecated:

```
 let records = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? [Record]
```

> 'unarchiveObject(with:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use
>   +unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: instead

Sounds simple as it is, I couldn't find a way to use the suggested method without getting errors in every combination I tried.

Any working example of this?

Comment: Try [`unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver/2919664-unarchivetoplevelobjectwithdata). Better check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51487622/6541007).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The usage of the new API to archive an array is a bit tricky.

You could have figured it out yourself if you wouldn't ignore the errors with `try?`

To be able to decode an array of a custom class with `unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:` you have to use the *plural* form `unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:` and specify both `NSArray`(!) and the custom class. Further your class must adopt `NSSecureCoding`

```
class Record : NSObject, NSSecureCoding {

   static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool {
        return true
    }

....

do {
    let archived = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [defaultRecord], requiringSecureCoding: false)

    let records = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [NSArray.self, Record.self], from: archived) as! [Record]
    print(records)
} catch { print(error) }
```

But why do you archive `defaultRecord` as array at all? If you archive the single object you can leave your class as it is and write

```
do {
    let archived = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: defaultRecord, requiringSecureCoding: false)

    let record = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: Record.self, from: archived)
    let records = [record]
    print(records)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Side note: Consider to serialize the class with `Codable`. It's *swiftier* and doesn't require inheritance from `NSObject`.

Comment: tnx! I will try btw I use swifty json and my class at the moment adopts these: class Record : NSObject, NSCoding, Codable

Comment: If your class already adopts `Codable` drop `SwiftyJSON`, `NSCoding` (and maybe even `NSObject)`

Comment: drop means I just remove SwiftyJson cocoa pod and things will continue working or I need a lot of refactoring?

Comment: You have to do some refactoring but it's worth it. `Codable` is built-in (no dependencies) and is much more efficient than `SwiftyJSON`. Eventually it will be less code than at the moment.

Comment: ok i will look into that. Btw is your answer still valid considering I adopt NSCoding, Codable at the moment?

Comment: Yes, both protocols look similar but are not related to each other.

Comment: Very subtle difference, thanks for pointing out the plural @vadian!

Answer (score 4):

The method above didn't worked for me for unarchiving, I did this and it worked:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClasses: [Record.self], from: archived)
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in the `Objective C` code, here it is:

```
// pointer to storage for error message
NSError *error = nil;

// read data from "dataPath" location
NSData *codedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];

// create a set of root class (the array) and the data object class
NSSet<Class> *classes = [NSSet setWithObjects:NSArray.class, Record.class, nil];

// read using classes, not only single class
NSArray *data = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:classes fromData:codedData error:&error];
```

Again, this is just a "translation" of the code @vadian correctly pointed out (and saved my day!).

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution to leave logic as is and hide the warning:

```swift
func clone<T: UIView>() throws -> T {
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
    unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = false
    return try unarchiver.decodeTopLevelObject(of: T.self, forKey: "root")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work fine. How did you determine the key should be "root"? Where can I read more about this?

Comment: I don't remember exactly but I guess if you save data to a file and open it with a text editor the 'root' word will be visible there. I just used the fastest approach here. The other possibility is to use system methods but I can't help much with that

Answer (score -3):

**Xcode 14 + iOS16**

Sample of code that archives and unarchives the record:

```
guard
    let archivedRecord = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: defaultRecord, requiringSecureCoding: false),
    let record = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(archivedRecord) as? Record
else { return nil }
```