# Cannot invoke 'unarchiveObject' with an argument list of type '(ofClasses: [NSObject.Type], from: Data)'

Tags: swift, mapbox, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver, mapbox-ios

As per Vadian answer [How to NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55982244/how-to-nskeyedunarchiver-unarchiveobject) for transforming Deprecated NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject to work in Swift 5/iOS 12+

I managed to transform archive part to work, but I'm still unable to fix the unarchive part, here is my code:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    guard let packs = MGLOfflineStorage.shared.packs else { return }
    for pack in packs
    {
        do
        {
            let userInfo = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(ofClasses: [NSObject.self], from: pack.context) as? [String: String]
            print("Suspending download of offline pack: “\(userInfo["name"] ?? "unknown")”")
        }
        catch
        {
            print("viewDidDisappear: KeyedUnarchiver Error")
        }
        pack.suspend()
    }
}
```

Which gives me an error:

> Cannot invoke 'unarchiveObject' with an argument list of type '(ofClasses: [NSObject.Type], from: Data)'

And this is the original iOS 12- Code:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

// When leaving this view controller, suspend offline downloads.
guard let packs = MGLOfflineStorage.shared.packs else { return }
for pack in packs {
if let userInfo = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: pack.context) as? [String: String] {
print("Suspending download of offline pack: “\(userInfo["name"] ?? "unknown")”")
}
pack.suspend()
}
}
```

Comment: `NSObject` is an abstract Objective-C base class. You have to be more specific. Obviously `context` contains a `[String:String]` dictionary so use at least `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Thanks vadian, I’m a bit unfamiliar with this, I tried but still get same error. Could you show me how you would fix it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing below :

```
let userInfo = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(ofClasses: [NSObject.self.classForKeyedUnarchiver()], from: pack.context) as? [String: String]
```

However, in objective-c below will work:

```
NSSet *allowedClasses = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSArray class],[NSMutableDictionary class], nil];
NSData *eObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"];
NSArray *dUuidList = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:allowedClasses fromData:eObject error:&error];
```